# Why is there only for some apps an error in the command for uninstalling apps with adb?

Tags: android, error-handling, adb

I wanted to delete some bloatware on my android phone but I get the error "Unknown option: --user" trying to deinstall preinstalled apps, even if it is something like flipboard and not directly samsung apps etc.

So I used the platform tools version 30.0.4 on Windows 10 with an Samsung Galaxy S3, android version 4.3 and the following commands:

```
adb devices

adb shell

pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.dropbox.android
Error: Unknown option: --user
shell@m0:/ $
```

same here:

```
shell@m0:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 0 org.wikipedia
Error: Unknown option: --user
```

but this worked for this app:

```
shell@m0:/ $ pm uninstall org.wikipedia
Success
```

but unfortunately not for others...
I checked for the correct writing with

```
pm list packages
```

and also tried: 'filename' and "filename"
So the other posts about this problem here were not helpful unfortunately.

does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Pm uninstall command does have one possible option, that is, `-k` to keep the user data:

```
pm uninstall [-k] PACKAGE
  -k: keep the data and cache directories around after package removal.
```

If you want, you can take a look at the `pm`'s source code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b8678d76c3e09d0d65255f3971b6112a48e19099/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java

Comment: Okay, thanks, however  "pm uninstall [-k] PACKAGE" or "pm uninstall PACKAGE" always return "Failure" for preinstalled apps.